# The date obtained by sprigboot console is inconsistent with the date obtained by the browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, time, simpledateformat

When I get a timestamp date data from the database, I convert it to the format I want through simpledateformat, and everything is normal here, and the date and time are correct when I test it with postman, but when I deploy it, when the program is in The date output after simpledateformat will be 8 hours less than now
My country timezone is in UTC-8

```
private String timestampToDateFormat(Timestamp timestamp) {
        Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.TAIWAN);
        return df.format(date);
    }
```

[CONSOLE TIME OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1LKK.jpg)

The time displayed on the browser after deploying

[browser time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HVEq.jpg)

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `Timestamp`, `Date`, `DatFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed, the last two in particular notoriously troublesome, and all are long outdated. Use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: It’s no doubt a time zone issue. (UTF-8 is a character encoding, not a time zone. Perhaps you mean that it is at UTC+8 or UTC-8.)

Comment: 8 hours ahead of my time zone, but the return is a string, will this also cause problems

Comment: Is the data type in the database `timestamp with time zone` or perhaps without time zone? For a timestamp prefer with time zone so that it truly defines a point in time. And what are the database time zone and the database session time zone?

Answer (score 0):

Set the time zone of the database to be consistent with your region.
I guess you are in Dongba District. If you are a MySQL database, you can set it this way

```
set global time_zone = ‘+8:00’;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, I found the answer. The reason is that the time zone of my computer system is UTC+8, and the time zone of my subordinates in JENKINS is UTC+0, so there will be a difference of 8 hours. The following is my approach. Set the entire springboot before initialization. Time zone

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalZoneConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    void started() {
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Taipei");
        TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
    }
}
```